# Есть ли ошибка в предложении в слове «модницы»?

Tags: грамматика, склонение, падежи, тавтология

Читаю статью про [дизайнерские платья](https://volga.news/604412/article/vybiraem-zhenskoe-dizajnerskoe-plate.html) на «Волга Ньюс» и вижу такое предложение: "В этом желании могут помочь дизайнерские изделия, помогая *модницы* на фоне других выглядеть стильно, модно, уверенно". Я же правильно понимаю, что слово, выделенное курсивом, должно писаться в дательном падеже "моднице"?

И еще один вопросик. Нормально ли в предложении писать "помогая моднице выглядеть модно"? Не будет ли это тавтологией?

Comment: "...могут помочь... помогая..." – тоже тавтология.

Comment: А первое предложение в этой статье не смущает? "Естественным **желаем** каждой женщины является стремление к красоте, **желая** оставаться красивой и привлекательной, уверенно шагая в ногу с трендами. В этом **желании**..."

Comment: Или модницам. @АлександрСтрелец: с желаниями не только тавтология, но и ДО, отнесённый непонятно к чему. Впрочем, думаю, вы это и так поняли тоже. ;)

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Да, не стал об этом писать, так как явно бросается в уши :)  Прочитал всю эту махалею...  там повтор на повторе и пр. Писать о красоте таким языком - ужас.

Comment: Да уж, полностью согласен.)))

Answer (score 1):

Безусловно, в предложении опечатка и должно быть **модниц*е***.

Тавтология также наличествует.